# pyQt: Scolling QScrollArea Not Each QTextEdit Individually

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qscrollarea

having many QTextEdit next to each other (I have a table subset HTML in them) I don't want them to get a scrollbar each when they overflow the window space.

I want the window to have a global scrollbar.
What's the best practice?

here the code as example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QRect, Qt

class MainWindow(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        text = ''
        for i in range(0,1000):
            text = '{0} {1}\n'.format(text, i)

        for i in range(0,10):
            textEdit = QTextEdit()
            layout.addWidget(textEdit)
            textEdit.setText(text)

        self.resize(600,400)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

I can add a container to the above and it gets rid of the scrollbars, but then I can not scroll anything at all

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QRect, Qt

class MainWindow(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        container = QFrame(self)
        container.resize(600,15000)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(container)

        text = ''
        for i in range(0,1000):
            text = '{0} {1}\n'.format(text, i)

        for i in range(0,10):
            textEdit = QTextEdit()
            layout.addWidget(textEdit)
            textEdit.setText(text)

        self.resize(600,400)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If the text-edits have different contents, they will not all scroll the same distance. So how could a *global* scrollbar work? Is it only supposed to scroll the text-edit that has the keyboard focus? Maybe it would be better if each text-edit only showed its scrollbar when you hovered over it with the mouse.

Comment: I am using the QtextEdit not as TextEdit but as a good tool to create custom Labels trhough HTML Subset. So those QTextEdit are like images, I don't need to scroll in them, I want to scroll the group of labels/QTextEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is [set the vertical scroll-bar policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBarPolicy-prop) on the text-edits and then [add the container widget to the scroll-area](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#setWidget):

```
class MainWindow(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        container = QFrame(self)
        container.resize(600,15000)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(container)

        text = ''
        for i in range(0,1000):
            text = '{0} {1}\n'.format(text, i)

        for i in range(0,10):
            textEdit = QTextEdit()
            layout.addWidget(textEdit)
            textEdit.setText(text)
            textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.setWidget(container)

        self.resize(625,400)

        self.show()
```

Comment: exactly! thanks... how can I do so that the container size adapts to the content?